# BackboneJS Reset Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a details view from where I load a dialog.

This dialog has a form where user can enter some values (corresponding to my model attributes)

I pass the model from my details view and set values in the same model (on change action of form fields)

Now the issue is the user can change some form fields (which updates my model values) and click on Cancel. However I want the model to go back to it's initial state when the dialog was loaded.
 **(NOT exactly the default state)**

How can I handle this ?

Comment: I guess you can assign the model to temp var in view initialization. On cancel action do this.model = temp and in view initialization bind model change to render the view like this.model.on('change', this.render, this);

Comment: do u mean clone the model ? coz that might still have the ref...

Comment: Yes you can clone the model and if you want to cancel the changes made to the original model revert back to initial state with cloned model attributes and re render the view on model change. The cloning will only be done on view initialiation

Comment: What about setting the values on the model when the form gets submitted?

Comment: Actually i need to do validation on change...so cannot do on save

Answer (score 1):

This is the best option to get the previous values.

```
model.set(model.previousAttributes());
```

Comment: so i have like multiple attributes within my model....would all of them get reverted back ?

Comment: Yes. It will revert all the changed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

With `model.previousAttributes()` you can get attributes only before the last call of `set` method.

You can try to save `state` manually before dialog starts up and set it back if user changes his mind

```
var state = this.model.toJSON();
...start up dialog...

...in case of cancel...
this.model.set(state);
```